# Having Problems with my program

Tags: java, text-files, java.util.scanner

My program is suppose to read environment.txt, and then repeatedly prompt the user for a variable name, and respond with the value of that variable, as defined in environment.txt . The user keeps entering variable names forever. (They can terminate the program with CTRL-C.)
In environment.txt var1 is equal to Hello var 2 is equal to GoodBye var3 is equal to Program and var4 is equal to Music. Every time my program prompts for a user's input when input is entered the program closes and doesn't output anything. Can someone make changes to my code i don't understand what is going on.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.*;
public class Environment {

    public static String VariableName() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a Variable: ");
        String userInput = input.nextLine();


        if (userInput == "var1")
        {
            userInput = "Hello";
            return userInput;
        }
        else if (userInput == "var2")
        {
            userInput = "GoodBye";
            return userInput;
        }
        else if (userInput == "var3")
        {
            userInput = "Program";
            return userInput;
        }
        else if (userInput == "var4")
        {
            userInput = "Music";
            return userInput;
        }
        else if (userInput == "CTRL-C");
        {
            System.exit(0);
        }
            return userInput;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        File file = new File("environment.txt");
        try{
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                String line = scanner.nextLine();
                System.out.println(line);

            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e){
            System.out.println("File Not Found");
        }
            VariableName();
        }


}
```

Comment: Well, you never call your method in the body of `main()`.

Answer (score 2):

Two things.

1) Look at [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java) for the proper way to compare strings in Java.

2) You don't have a loop in your `VariableName()` method, so you only go around once, then quit.

I would print out the user input, and for each test that you fail, print a "thisString is not equal to thatString". This will help you understand how the program is actually behaving.

That should get you there.

Answer (score 1):

There were many issues in your source,

1) The below src will cause to call every time  `System.exit(0);` because you are closing the else if statement with `semi-clolon (;)` which completes the `else-if` clause.

```
else if (userInput == "CTRL-C");

{
 System.exit(0);
}
```

2) Not using [String.equals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) or [String.equalsIgnoreCase](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase%28java.lang.String%29) methods for comparing.

3) Not looping in the *VariableName* method to get continuous input from user

Comment: Good eye for that semicolon!